# Adding spaces to replace occurrences of punctuation followed by alphanumeric words without white space inbetween

Tags: php

In my bio information users sometimes input sentences without using the proper spacing, like this:

```
$bio = 'Hey there,I'm Tom!And I'm 25';
```

I use preg replace to fix the commas:

```
$bio = str_replace(",", ", ", $bio);
```

Which echo's:

```
$bio = 'Hey there, I'm Tom!And I'm 25';
```

How do I do this for all the other punctuation signs except ' (from I'm) ?

Any ideas?

Comment: [`preg_replace`](http://in.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use preg_replace with arrays.

first create an array signs to replace like:

```
$signs = array('/,/', '/!/', '/?/');
```

than another array with the replacements

```
$replacement = array(', ', '! ', '? ');
```

now use both arrays with preg_replace:

```
preg_replace($signs, $replacement, $bio);
```

to be sure the next sign is'nt already a whitspace you could use a more complex regular expression for each character like this one:

```
$signs = array('/,(\S)/', '/!(\S)/', '/?(\S)/');
$replacement = array(', $1', '! $1', '? $1');
```

http://php.net/manual/de/function.preg-replace.php

Comment: One problem with this solution, if someone has "Hello World! This is a test." You would end up with "Hello World! This is a test. " You need to ensure that the character after the punctuation is not a space before you replace it, or after it completes, run through it again replacing double spaces with single spaces.

Comment: you are right on this. so he needs more complex regular expressions for every sign.

Comment: I use rtrim($xbio,',.;:- _!$&#'); to remove the last punctuation mark.